# How to write encrypted app data and decrypte it

Tags: android, security, encryption

I want to store my app data in a file so it could be accessed every time from the app - for example: money, user score, user current sprite...
I have never seen encryption in my life, and I wanted to know if there is an easy way to encrypt data and write it to the phone, and then decrypt it next time the app is open.
If there is no easy way, it would be great if someone could explain how the encryption/decryption works to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SharedPreferences.
I've used them, and you dont need to encrypt the data.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref

EXAMPLE(from developer.android):

```
public class Calc extends Activity {
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
   super.onCreate(state);
   . . .

   // Restore preferences
   SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
   boolean silent = settings.getBoolean("silentMode", false);
   setSilent(silent);
}

@Override
protected void onStop(){
   super.onStop();

  // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
  // All objects are from android.context.Context
  SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
  editor.putBoolean("silentMode", mSilentMode);

  // Commit the edits!
  editor.commit();
}
}
```

Comment: We can be able to pull preference files, db on rooted devices. Encrypting sensitive data stored in preferences in necessary.

Comment: No matter how you encrypt it, if you need to decrypt it there wil be a method.
You can decompile the source and find it.
Or more simply use GameCIH.
If u use that, it doesn't matter if it's decrypted or not.
Don't use decryption then, but cloud syncing, and check for suspicious stuff.

Comment: Thank you guys, but I didnt fully understand: If I use SharedPreferences and I dont use cloud syncing, because I really have no idea how to or what it is, Is it ok to not ecrypt or is there a method I have to check?

Comment: In general encryption only makes sense if a possible attacker cannot access the decryption key and/or the program state. Otherwise it just makes it slightly harder (that's called obfuscation). Basically that means that if the attacker has full control over the target device(s) - e.g. one or more rooted phones - then encryption in itself is never full proof.